# complex integral problem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to evaluate this
$$\int_{c} \dfrac {|z| e^{z} }{z^2}$$
where C is the circunference with radius 2. I have tried to apply the Cauchy formula but $|z|e^{z} $ is not holomorfic. I know the resut is$ 4 \pi i$ I have also tried to do it as a line int, but i dont manage anything

Comment: the circle is centered at zero?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The integrand isn't holomorphic, but $\lvert z\rvert$ is constant on the contour, so ...